# PayPal standard IPN chargeback settlement message missing required 'business' field

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, missing-data

We've been using PayPal standard for about 10 years now. Only today we've received an IPN message generated as a result of chargeback settlement - and noticed some fields are missing.

Here are the fields as confirmed in the PayPal IPN history page (for privacy reasons, the 'payer_email' field value is obscured):

> txn_type=adjustment&payment_date=03:32:10 Feb 09, 2016
>   PST&payment_gross=&mc_currency=CAD&verify_sign=ATjxb9PR1aNXqPs2fhQE00D26f.QAu0.eUdqXZNZvOMDQsa1Hd3cSPz8&payer_status=verified&payer_email=paypal@XXXX.ca&txn_id=14V55619FE764784J&parent_txn_id=1XH95106BE741351U&payer_id=W2PJ5ZGY8E9VG&invoice=673D082E-D1F9-4D22-A535-6494F679CDCE&reason_code=chargeback_settlement&payment_status=Completed&payment_fee=-20.00&mc_gross=-300.00&charset=UTF-8&notify_version=3.8&ipn_track_id=7ecc9a13ccaa0

From what I see, the expected "business" field is missing. See the IPN reference at  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/:

> Email address or account ID of the payment recipient (that is, the
>   merchant). Equivalent to the values of receiver_email (if payment is
>   sent to primary account) and business set in the Website Payment HTML.

This 'business' field was always in all the other IPN messages (even those for refunds), and our app relies on its value to identify the correct merchant.

Anyone else experienced this issue? (To me it looks like a PayPal IPN bug.)

Answer (score 0):

The IPN you got for the chargeback includes a parent_txn_id which is the txn_id from the original payment that is being disputed.

So in your system you should be able to relate this IPN back to that one based on that original txn_id, and in that original order data you would be able to see the "business" parameter associated with it.

Comment: Yes, that is true Andrew. But why is this IPN so different from all the other IPN messages? All the other IPN messages have this "business" field, Moreover, according to the PayPal specs that field should be included in every IPN message. To me, this still looks like a PayPal bug.

Comment: It's just a different type of transaction.  It's not a payment, so it doesn't have the same sort of variables that payment transactions have.  It's not a bug.

Comment: It's a refund transaction, and all the refund IPN messages always include the "business" field. Plus I do not see it stated in the IPN specs that this field will not be in the charge-back settlement IPN messages. (BTW - I am fine with many other fields missing. But not this one. Yes, you are right, I could go down the chain and fish out the "business" field value from the original IPN message saved in the database. But this is extra work that is not needed for all the other IPN messages.)

Comment: It's not a refund transaction.  It's a dispute transaction.  If the transaction is refunded you would get a separate IPN for that.